# Pass Parameters in cmd while opening Power BI Desktop

Tags: powerbi

I am using a Power BI Desktop Template.

The Tables are created dynamically. The two highlighted parameters together for a table name. I am planning to open the report from another application, is it possible to pass these parameters via the command line when the report is opened? This is to make things easier for the user without expecting him to edit the parameters after opening.

[image: query parameters]

Thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot do that. You may want to vote/comment on this [suggestion](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/33013216-command-line-arguments-to-control-startup), or add a new one. Also have a look at [this](http://biinsight.com/power-bi-desktop-query-parameters-part-1/) if you haven't already.