# Instantiate Power BI template from script

Tags: scripting, powerbi

I have an application that generates customer-specific datasets of a predefined format. These data sets can be queried via parameterized calls to a REST-API - i.e. the query needs to contain a `customer id`. The application generates new data periodically, which can be queried from the REST API by altering additional parameters, e.g. `date`.

The parameterization in Power BI can be achieved using [Power BI Templates](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/de-de/blog/deep-dive-into-query-parameters-and-power-bi-templates/).
As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52146213/pass-parameters-in-cmd-while-opening-power-bi-desktop), these parameters have to be manually set in the form that pops up when opening the template. Since new data is supposed to be queried for a lot of different customers, I cannot and do not want to set the parameters within the graphical user interface.

I opened this thread for asking two questions:

- Is it possible by now to instantiate Power BI templates from a text-based environment? (e.g. shell script, python etc.)
- If not, is there an alternative solution to this problem? Can you point me in the right direction?

**Important**: For alternative solutions, please keep in mind that the data used is sensitive - e.g. it is important that data of different customers remains completely isolated.

Comment: Why not make only one report and filter the data using [Row Level Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-admin-rls) depending on the user, so he will see only the relevant data?

Comment: @AndreyNikolov 's solution seems optimal. If it was an Answer it would get my vote and a shot at that precious rep. Or do you require the use of Power BI Desktop?

Comment: To my understanding, this approach first retrieves and then filters the data, whereas in my use case the customer id is part of the URL, e.g. I want to submit a GET request to example.com/<customer id>/<date>/... .

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your details, I am sure the REST API has a route for getting all Customer IDs. 
Once you have a table/list of all these Customer IDs, you can write a function in the query editor which iterates over each of these IDs, calling the REST API for each and then returning a list of all the results.

**Example of looping:**

[image]